# WPF: Getting TreeViewItem's constituent controls

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate, treeviewitem

how can I get the constituent controls making up the TreeViewItem in code if they are inside a hierarichicaldatatemplate?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\module.ico" />
        <local:RenamingNode Name="RenamableNode" Text="{Binding Name}" VstaObject="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" OnRename="OnRenameOccured"  />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

So programatically when I get an event with a TreeViewItem as the source, I want to be able to get the local:RenamingNode, but I can't get the TreeViewItem's descendants.

Thanks,

Ilya

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Doubtless there is a better way, as always, and you will doubtless add extra checks such as checking the Child(ren) count and/or getting/checking type/name of children in a loop etc. but the basic technique works, well it did in my app although I have a Grid instead of a StackPanel.

```
private object FindContentTemplatePart(TreeViewItem treeViewItem) 
{ 
    if (treeViewItem != null) 
    { 
        var header = (ContentPresenter)treeViewItem.Template.FindName("PART_Header", treeViewItem);

        if (header != null) 
        { 
            StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(header,0);

            return stackPanel.Children[2];
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FrameworkTemplate.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) to find the header content presenter in the TreeView item control template, and then again to find the part you want in the data template.

```
private object FindContentTemplatePart(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
{
    if (treeViewItem != null)
    {
        var header = treeViewItem.Template.FindName("PART_Header", treeViewItem) as ContentPresenter;
        if (header != null)
        {
            return header.ContentTemplate.FindName("RenamableNode", header);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could also walk the visual tree manually with the methods on [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper_members.aspx).

Comment: This does not work because the header does not have a ContentTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this will be the same in WPF as silverlight (this is the silverlight version)

```
(treeViewItem.HeaderTemplate.LoadContent() as StackPanel).FindName("RenamableNode")
```

Comment: The questioner needs to find the named instance for a particular TreeViewItem. Yours would give back a name instance for a new instantiation which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above Solutions works in Silverlight 
but this seems to work.

```
<common:HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="myHierarchicalTemplate"  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"  >
        <StackPanel x:Name="spTreeItem"  Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
    </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Following the code

```
 TreeViewItem item = TreeViewWorkarounds.ContainerFromItem(trtFolders, trtFolders.SelectedItem);
 Grid ItemGrid = (Grid) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, 0);
 Button ItemGridButton = (Button)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ItemGrid, 2);
 Grid ButtonGrid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ItemGridButton, 0);
 ContentPresenter CP = (ContentPresenter)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ButtonGrid, 1);
 ContentPresenter CPchlild = (ContentPresenter)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(CP, 0);
 StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(CPchlild, 0);
```