# How to parse Children of TreeviewItem correctly in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a `TreeView` control in my WPF program,which gets data from MySQL server and show `databases` and `tables`:

```
Server
...Databases
    ...Tables
```

What I want is when I click an item in the `Treeview`,I can get the `Server/Databases/Tables`' name.However,after hours testing,I still could not get the name.

**HierarchicalDataTemplate of server**

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
     DataType="{x:Type local:ServerViewModel}"  
     ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Figures/server.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServerName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The other two are similar, except that `HierarchicalDataTemplate` of table does not have `ItemsSource`.

As I'm using MvvmLight pattern,I pass the `SelectedItem` as `CommandParameter`to `ViewModel`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding tableSelected}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=MyTreeview}"
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the ViewModel,I delared a command to handle `SelectedItemChanged` event.I implemented the **Execute()** method as below,yet it did not work.Whenever I click a TreeviewItem,an unhandled exception `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` would be thrown.

```
private void GetSelectedItem(object parameter)
{
    var item = parameter as TreeViewItem;
    StackPanel stackpanel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, 0);
    TextBlock textblock = (TextBlock)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(stackpanel, 1);
    MessageBox.Show(textblock.Text);
}
```

---

**Update**

---

**Command**

```
public ICommand tableSelected { get; private set; }//In the ViewModel
```

---

```
tableSelected = new RelayCommand<object>((obj) => GetSelectedItem(obj), (obj) => true);
//Implemented in the ViewModel's constructor
```

I've read several related posts on Stackoverflow,like [How I can get content of TreeViewItem in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125997/how-i-can-get-content-of-treeviewitem-in-wpf),[WPF: Getting TreeViewItem's constituent controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250630/wpf-getting-treeviewitems-constituent-controls),yet I still can not get it right.Please help,thanks.

Comment: *"declared a command to handle SelectedItemChanged"* that is just wrong. Note that *SelectedItemChanged* is a **DependencyProperty**. In your respective ViewModel, create a property like "SelectedWhatever" (implement change notification for it via `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and then just bind this ViewModel property to *SelectedItem*.

Comment: Which line of your code threw the exception you mentioned?

Comment: Where are the properties of the names defined you tried and failed to get? Show it to us.

Comment: There's no problem with my binding.I'm using MvvmLight,and in fact I declare a `RelayCommand`.I'll update my question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: What I want to get is the the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` in the `TreeviewItem`,which I'm trying to parse.

Comment: You mean, you want to get the Text property from outside the TreeViewItem's ItemTemplate? But i don't understand... the Text property is bound to the ServerName of the ViewModel (in your example). Why can't you not just access the ServerName property?

Comment: I just find it straightforward to get Text from `TextBlock`.You see,my `Treeview` has three level,and they are binded to different `ViewModel`s.If I access namely,`ServerName`,do I have to get the current instance of `DatabaseViewModel`?Besides,there's a complex inheritance relationship of my `ViewModel`s...Basically I rewrite `Database.cs` of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).I'm a newbie to WPF so this indeed frustrated me a lot :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53895/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-chenxiao)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that what I was doing previously is totally wrong.The **SelectedItem** is not a collections of UI control,but purely an instance the same type as that of **DataType**.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type local:DatabaseViewModel}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Figures/database.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatabaseName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The code above is part of my treeview.If I click a treeviewitem which uses this template,what I get is a **DatabaseViewModel** instance,rather than a **StackPanel** or its children.This is really misleading for WPF beginners.